# API App with NInject doesnt work on IIS, It only works on debugger Visual Studio

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, api, iis

I have an API application that works perfectly on Visual Studio 2015 debugger; I am trying to publish my application on IIS (I have installed  the server by Control panel Turn on/off Windows features).

My application has a security system to check that any request is from a user registered, any request pass first throw `ApiAuthorizationFilter`, resolve the token that is composed by Base64 string, it comes in the header as **Authorization** and returns the specific `HttpStatusCode` with JSON.

The Exception Occurs after deploy, if I run a test on the application that is at IIS throws `NullReferenceException` at `Filter.ApiAuthorizationFilter`, but if I run the same application on Visual Studio - it works.

This is the error message:

> 500: Internal Server Error
>   "Message": "An error has occurred."
>   "ExceptionMessage": "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."
>   "ExceptionType": "System.NullReferenceException"
>   "StackTrace": " at API.CARDS.Models.Filter.ApiAuthorizationFilter.OnAuthorization(HttpActionContext actionContext) at System.Web.Http.Filters.AuthorizationFilterAttribute.OnAuthorizationAsync(HttpActionContext actionContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken) --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at System.Web.Http.Filters.AuthorizationFilterAttribute.d__2.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.d__1.MoveNext()"

Here is the code:

*ApiAuthorizationFilter*

```
public class ApiAuthorizationFilter : AuthorizationFilterAttribute
{
    [Inject]
    public IEncryptionSystemService service { get; set; }

    [Inject]
    public IUserService userService { get; set; }

    public override void OnAuthorization(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        //Hace una petición (request) al actionContext
        HttpRequestMessage request = actionContext.Request;
        try
        {
            //Establece la cultura (Ejemplo: es-MX) para los mensajes i18n
            string culture = actionContext.Request.Headers.AcceptLanguage.ToString();
            if (culture.Length == 5)
            {
                Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo(culture);
                Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(culture);
            }
            //Crea un token con los valores que se obtienen del actionContext, mismos que serán las credenciales para accesar.
            string token = actionContext.Request.Headers.GetValues("Authorization").FirstOrDefault().Replace("Credentials", "").Trim();
            //Desencripta las credenciales con el servicio del tipo IEncryptionService.
            string[] userPass = service.DecryptText(token);
            User model = new User { email = userPass[0], password = userPass[1] };
            ////Verifica que sean correctas las credenciales que ser obtuvieron del token.
            AuthorizationResult result = userService.LoginUser(model);
            switch (result)
            {
                case AuthorizationResult.ACCESS_GRANTED:
                    User user = new User { email = model.email };
                    ApiIdentity identity = new ApiIdentity(user);
                    ApiPrincipal principal = new ApiPrincipal(identity);
                    Thread.CurrentPrincipal = principal;
                    break;
                case AuthorizationResult.ACCESS_DENIED:
                    actionContext.Response = request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, "ErrorResources.NotFound");
                    break;
                case AuthorizationResult.PERMISSION_DENIED:
                    actionContext.Response = request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized, "ErrorResources.Unauthorized");
                    break;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw;
            //Si existe un error durante la petición, regresa un estatus de InternalServerError (Error interno del Servidor).
            //actionContext.Response = request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, string.Format("ErrorResources.AuthenticationError ---- {0}",e.Message));

        }
    }
}
```

[Image response from the debugger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gx0NP.png)

[Image response from IIS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ssnn.png)

Comment: Publish the PDB's so you can at least see the line number. I suspect your DI is not working.

Comment: where can I find the PDB's if my visual studio has the default configuration? and Do you mean the Dependency Injection? I have the same feeling about the NInject, but I don't know why it works only on Debug

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer after a big research!, This answer is for **API Application with NInject,** Leppie was right the issue was around  **Dependency Injection Configuration.**

First I had to clean my packets installed from **NuGet**, I had to reinstall  **Ninject** with these packets.

- Ninject
- Ninject.web.WebApi
- Ninject.web.WebApi.WebHost -- I was missing this one, **this is required for IIS support**
- Ninject.MVC3
- Ninject.web.Common
- Ninject.web.Common.WebHost -- Update this one to last version (3.2.3), **this is required for IIS support**

After that check your class **NInjectWebCommon.cs**, in the method called **CreateKernel()** I had this line

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = new NinjectDependencyResolver(kernel);
```

You need to remove it, because this will throw

> Error activating ModelValidatorProvider using binding from
>   ModelValidatorProvider to NinjectDefaultModelValidatorProvider

If everything is OK! your application will run on **IIS Server**.

these files are my last configuration of NInject in the App_Start folder

**NinjectWebCommon.cs**

```
public static class NinjectWebCommon
{
    private static readonly Bootstrapper bootstrapper = new Bootstrapper();

    /// <summary>
    /// Starts the application
    /// </summary>
    public static void Start()
    {
        DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule(typeof(OnePerRequestHttpModule));
        DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule(typeof(NinjectHttpModule));
        bootstrapper.Initialize(CreateKernel);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Stops the application.
    /// </summary>
    public static void Stop()
    {
        bootstrapper.ShutDown();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates the kernel that will manage your application.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>The created kernel.</returns>
    private static IKernel CreateKernel()
    {
        var kernel = new StandardKernel();
        try
        {
            kernel.Bind<Func<IKernel>>().ToMethod(ctx => () => new Bootstrapper().Kernel);
            kernel.Bind<IHttpModule>().To<HttpApplicationInitializationHttpModule>();

            RegisterServices(kernel);

           // GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = new NinjectDependencyResolver(kernel);
            return kernel;
        }
        catch
        {
            kernel.Dispose();
            throw;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Load your modules or register your services here!
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="kernel">The kernel.</param>
    private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
    {
        // kernel.BindFilter<ApiAuthorizationFilter>(FilterScope.Controller, 0).WhenControllerHas<ApiAuthorizationFilter>();

        NInjectHelper.SetupKernel(kernel);
        kernel.Bind<IEncryptionSystemService>().To<EncryptionSystemService>();
        kernel.Bind<IUserService>().To<UserService>();
        kernel.Bind<IRoleService>().To<RoleService>();
        kernel.Bind<IStatusService>().To<StatusService>();
        kernel.Bind<ICardService>().To<CardService>();
        kernel.Bind<ICardTypeService>().To<CardTypeService>();


    }

}
```

**NinjectResolver.cs**

```
 public class NinjectResolver : NinjectScope, IDependencyResolver
{
    private IKernel _kernel;

    public NinjectResolver(IKernel kernel)
        : base(kernel)
    {
        _kernel = kernel;
    }

    public IDependencyScope BeginScope()
    {
        return new NinjectScope(_kernel.BeginBlock());
    }
}
```

**NinjectScope.cs**

```
  public class NinjectScope : IDependencyScope
{
    protected IResolutionRoot resolutionRoot;

    public NinjectScope(IResolutionRoot kernel)
    {
        resolutionRoot = kernel;
    }

    public object GetService(Type serviceType)
    {
        IRequest request = resolutionRoot.CreateRequest(serviceType, null, new Parameter[0], true, true);
        return resolutionRoot.Resolve(request).SingleOrDefault();
    }

    public IEnumerable<object> GetServices(Type serviceType)
    {
        IRequest request = resolutionRoot.CreateRequest(serviceType, null, new Parameter[0], true, true);
        return resolutionRoot.Resolve(request).ToList();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        IDisposable disposable = (IDisposable)resolutionRoot;
        if (disposable != null) disposable.Dispose();
        resolutionRoot = null;
    }
}
```

**IMPORTANT! For SQL Server Users** 
As you can see on my **ApiFilterConfiguration** I have this line    `AuthorizationResult result = userService.LoginUser(model);`
this **userService** is a class that I have created with the method **LoginUser(model)** this method gets a model from the **Request Headers** and goes to **SQL SERVER** to verify the user exist.

If you installed **SQL Server** with *default configuration* as me, maybe you have another issue that throws **Null reference after a consult**, check this topic **[Login failed for user IIS APPPOOL\AppPool4.5 or APPPOOL\ASP.NET](http://www.devcurry.com/2015/08/login-failed-for-user-iis.html)** maybe you need to create a login for **IIS** on your **SQLSERVER**